# How to add 'not empty' constraint on a field in table in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, null, constraints

I'm using MySQL database server**(Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log - (Ubuntu))**.

There in one table titled `'users'` in a database. In the table `'users'` there is one column titled `'full_name'`.

Following are the constraints on it

```
Name : full_name
Type : `varchar(255)`
Collation : `latin1_swedish_ci`
Attributes :
Null : No
Default : None
Extra :
```

The issue I'm facing with this column(`'full_name'`) is some where from PHP code **empty** value gets inserted in this column though I've added a **NOT NULL** constraint.

I want to avoid doing that thing from anywhere. That is empty/blank/white space characters/NULL should not get insert into this column. I want to do it from the database table itself rather than making modifications in PHP code.

Can someone please help me in preventing insertion of such values in this column?

One more thing is there are few records present in this table that contains **NULL** value in the field `'full_name'`. I think those values have been present before I added the **NOT NULL** constraint to the column `'full_name'`. My another doubt is are these `NULL` values affecting the column?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check constraint like this :

```
full_name VARCHAR(45) CHECK (full_name <> '')
```

**UPDATE:**

As [@vhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3480271/vhu) pointed out :

> CHECK() is parsed but ignored as part of the CREATE statement.

So you have to add a **TRIGGER** before an **INSERT** for your `users` table.

This TRIGGER will be called **before** the INSERT and he will check if the value to set to `a` is empty. If it's true, `a` will be set to NULL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW 
IF new.`a` = '' THEN SET new.`a` = NULL; END IF; END;
```

`test` is the name of the table, `test_BIN` is the name of the TRIGGER and `a` is the name of one column of the table `test`.

*Note : This code has been generated by MySQL Workbench.*

Comment: wow, very nice.
I didn't know we can do this at column definition

Comment: No, it doesn't work. `CHECK()` is parsed but ignored as part of the `CREATE` statement. See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) for details: _"The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."_

Comment: @vhu - You're right, I have tested this constraint with MySQL Workbench and he has been ignored. I have to add a trigger.